# Is `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-config` discontinued?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The current version (`4.7.2`) of the [spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/v4.7.2/spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies/pom.xml) has no mention of `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-config`.
And there is only 1 **release** version of the artifact in Maven: [3.4.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/spring-cloud-gcp-starter-config/3.4.2).

Is it discontinued?
Or perhaps published to another repository that needs to be manually included.

The git [repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/v4.7.2/spring-cloud-gcp-starters/spring-cloud-gcp-starter-config/pom.xml) still exists.
I've expected to find `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-config` version `4.7.2` in the Maven Central repo, but no such luck.

**Edit:**
It looks like this artifact can be replaced with:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Edit 2:
Those dependencies are a replacement - confirmed.
The question remains if the overall mechanism is still supported by GCP.
Is there any plan to scrap it?